# Can a cold surface emit heat radiation?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, thermal-radiation

If I place a hot body behind a cold glass, it would transmit the hot bodys radiation and thus pass heat radiation.

Could the glass surface still be considered cold in terms of contact temperature, or is glass passing a large amount of heat radiation always hot itself?

Comment: Hot and cold are relative and subjective terms. You should just compare temperatures, which are objective and absolute.

Comment: You are mixing radiation and diffusion. What does hot or cold mean in a radiation context? Any surface emit thermal radiation even at very low temperature the black body effect exist

Comment: Your title question and your question in the body are very different.  The title asks if it can be emit radiation; the second asks if something can still be considered cold after being involved in heat transfer (if I understand the body correctly).

Comment: This article may be useful: https://www.physicskey.com/43/heat-transfer

Comment: The article doesn't mention the effect of 'transparency' or something like that I think.
I try to edit the question to be more clear.

Comment: I'm sorry but ?i don't understand question either? What is contact termperature.

Comment: The glass will absorb some of the radiation from a hotter body near it. Some radiation will pass thru the glass. The amount absorbed will go into heating the glass. But the glass is emitting radiation as well, It will radiate more thermal energy as it gets warmer. Givin a long enough time both objects will become the same temperature.

Comment: There is no such thing as "heat radiation".  All bodies that are warmer than absolute zero (which means all bodies) emit radiant energy whose spectrum depends on the temperature.

Comment: I am pretty sure I know what he's asking about. He's wondering if, because the glass is _passing_ thermal radiation from a hot body at high temperature, whether that allows one to in a way consider the glass itself as "hot" given that an object placed _near the glass_ will then be able to heat to high temperatures as a result.

Answer (score 1):

What is cold and what is hot are both relative descriptions of temperature different to everyone. This is why in scientific fields the term "Kelvin" is used which is an absolute temperature related to the energy of an object, where 0K is no energy at all.

Every object with a non-zero temperature emits radiation, the intensity and wavelength depends on the temperature of the object. In the case of a glass of hot water and cold water, the cold water will not radiate as strongly as the warm water and thus the cold and hot waters' temperature gradients will not be the same. After a sufficient amount of time has passed, the two glasses will be in equilibrium.

With higher temperatures, the peak wavelength on a graph of intensity-wavelength becomes shorter and shorter. This is why for example steel is cold and grey at rest under no heating, but turns yellow/red/white as we heat it upp sufficiently, the peak wavelength of the emission moves out of the sub-red spectrum and into the visual spectrum.

I hope this answered your question